# Setting a default value with react-select not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-select

I have a simple React component which gets an initial state:

```
this.state = {
  currentObject: {
    isYounger: false
  }
}
```

I then render a `react-select` with the default value of `this.state.currentObject.isYounger`:

```
    <Select
      name={"age"}
      value={this.state.currentObject.isYounger}
      onChange={newValue => this.addIsYoungerValue(newValue)}
      options={isYoungerOptions}
    />
```

For some reason, the value is not set. Why is this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqm14m8q5x?fontsize=14)

Version:

`"react-select": "^2.4.2",`

Comment: Can you please specify the version you are using of react-select?

Comment: Thanks @DharaVihol I have updated the OP with the version

Comment: It seems like you are having issue because you are trying to set `Boolean` value. Can you try it once with String value, so that we can understand the root cause and it will help to resolve the issue. @A7DC

Comment: Thanks @DharaVihol, I've updated to use string values instead of boolean, but that does nothing. I've updated the OP with an editable sandbox also

Comment: You can also provide `defaultValue` prop. As described here. 
[https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

Comment: I've already tried that by doing `defaultValue={isYoungerOptions[0].value}` but it does not work

Comment: Please check the answer and as well as sandbox changes @A7DC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here the issue is not with state selection, the actual issue is that the label is not getting displayed.

So, as per your `addIsYoungerValue` function you are setting the value of `this.state.currentObject.isYounger` to whole object. i.e. `{ value: true, label: "Younger" }`. So, the issue can be solved by changing the value of initial state by below.

```
this.state = {
      array: [],
      currentObject: {
        isYounger: { value: true, label: "Younger" }
      }
    };
```

And hurrey, the default value label will be shown..

Answer (score 10):

There is an alternate way to use **value** as your **defaultValue**. In my case I have used "id" and "industry" instead of "label" and "value"

```
this.state = {
     interested_industries: [{id:"ANY", industry:"ANY"}]
}
```

And in Select component:-

```
<Select 
    name="interested_industries"
    options={industries}
    value={interested_industries}
    getOptionLabel={ x => x.id}
    getOptionValue={ x => x.industry}
    onChange={this.handleSelect}
    isMulti
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me hours of hair tearing!

Answer (score 9):

Your `defaultValue` or `value` must be objects. In your case like this:

```
defaultValue={isYoungerOptions[0]}
```

or

```
this.state = {
   array: [],
   currentObject: {
     isYounger: { value: "true", label: "Younger" }
   }
 };
```

Here an [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yv04xyllp9).

Answer (score 1):

The **defaultValue** prop only works on mount / first render of the component

Comment: what if i get the options with an api call?